# How can OpportunitySplits take up twice the space of an Opportunity?

Tags: data-storage, opportunity-split

[image: OpportunitySplit Storage Usage]

As per the above image I have 20K Opportunities and consequentially 40K splits. It seems that there is a revenue and overlay split record for each opportunity. Fair enough. What I can't understand is how is it possible that each of those split records takes up the same amount of space as an entire opportunity record? How can splits take up twice the amount of space as the opportunity record they represent?

Thanks, Greg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [Data and File Storage Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm), which basically explains how storage works. All you really need to know is that most types of records require 2 KB of storage, *regardless of their physical size on disk*.

Imagine you have 500 custom fields on an object, each with a total of 255 characters of storage. If you do the math, you'll see that totals 127,500 characters of storage, not including metadata, standard fields, indexing, etc, and yet this object uses no more space than a task record with no customization. Some types of fields may consume additional space, however.

Salesforce has determined that 2 KB tends to average out over many types of records over all clients. Most full-sized objects require 2 KB of storage per object. This is the price we pay for being able to fully customize an object (of which sales splits are). You'll notice that Campaign Members also count towards storage space, and you can easily have thousands or millions of members in a campaign.